# First value is missing in list fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to build a notes app and my arrayadapter is not taking the first value.

Main Activity :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Models.Note;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityFragment.Onqwertylistener{

    static ArrayList<Note> ar = new ArrayList<Note>();
    static arraylistclass newar = new arraylistclass();
    static ArrayAdapter adapter=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final MainActivity thisobject = this;
        FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson1 = new Gson();
        String json = mPrefs.getString("yaah", "");
        newar = gson1.fromJson(json, arraylistclass.class);
        if (newar != null)
            ar = newar.getAr();
        else {
            ar = new ArrayList<Note>();
        }
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ar);
        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //adapter.add(no);
                int pos;
                pos = ar.size();
                ar.add(new Note("", pos +1));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (newar != null)
                    newar.setAr(ar);
                SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor = mPrefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(newar);
                prefseditor.putString("yaah", json);
                prefseditor.apply();
                onNoteSelected(pos);
                Toast.makeText(thisobject,"Pos"+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();

        MainActivityFragment mainfragment=new MainActivityFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,mainfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }
    @Override
    public void onNoteSelected(int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, opennote.class);
        intent.putExtra("opennote", pos);//ar.get(position).getId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

opennote :

```
package com.example.dhrumil.notes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Models.Note;


public class opennote extends AppCompatActivity {

    int x;
    String val;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opennote);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        x=intent.getIntExtra("opennote", 0);
        ArrayList<Note> ar;
        ar=MainActivityFragment.getar();
        val=ar.get(x).getNote();
        EditText e1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        e1.setText(val);
    }
    public void onPause() {
        EditText s;
        super.onPause();
        s= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        ArrayList<Note> ar;
        ar=MainActivityFragment.getar();
        ar.get(x).setNote(s.getText().toString());

    }
}
```

Fragment :

```
package com.example.dhrumil.notes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import Models.Note;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static com.example.dhrumil.notes.MainActivity.ar;
import static com.example.dhrumil.notes.MainActivity.adapter;
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends ListFragment {
    Onqwertylistener Callback;
    boolean b=false;

    public interface Onqwertylistener
    {
        public void onNoteSelected(int pos);
    }
    static ArrayList getar()
    {
        return ar;
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    }
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Activity activity=(Activity) context;
        try {
            Callback = (Onqwertylistener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }


    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Callback=(Onqwertylistener) getActivity();

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //adapter.remove(ar.get(position));
                final int pos=position;
                AlertDialog.Builder diabox=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                diabox.setMessage("Do you want to delete this note ?").setTitle("ALERT");
                diabox.setCancelable(true);
                diabox.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        adapter.remove(ar.get(pos));
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                diabox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog deletedia=diabox.create();
                deletedia.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    /*@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);



        try {
            Callback = (Onqwertylistener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }



        /*gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridv);;


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ar);
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, android.R.layout., ar);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Callback.onNoteSelected(position);
            }
        });*/
        /*if (!b) {
            gridView.setNumColumns(1);
        } else {
            gridView.setNumColumns(3);
        }
        gridView.setLongClickable(true);
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //adapter.remove(ar.get(position));
                final int pos = position;
                AlertDialog.Builder diabox = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisObject);
                diabox.setMessage("Do you want to delete this note ?").setTitle("ALERT");
                diabox.setCancelable(true);
                diabox.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        adapter.remove(ar.get(pos));
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                diabox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog deletedia = diabox.create();
                deletedia.show();
                return true;
            }
        });*/




            //}


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Notify the parent activity of selected item
        Callback.onNoteSelected(position);
        // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout

        //getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

}
```

I am new to Android and application development so please suggest me any changes/improvements in the code.

Comment: More detailed information on the is needed. Is an exception thrown? What line does the error occur on?

Comment: There is no error at all but the list fragment does not show the first value.